# How to make image mask appear on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On my site I have a profile page with the user's photo.  When the user hover's over their photo, I want a transparent mask with some text to appear over the image that the user can then click that brings up a modal where the user can update their profile picture.

I can't get it to work. Demo is below:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.profile-image').hover(function() {
     $('.mask-layer').css("visibility", "visible");
   }, function() {
     $('.mask-layer').css("visibility", "hidden");
   });


 });
```

```css
.profile-image-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.profile-image-container .profile-image {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: auto;
}
.profile-image-container .mask-layer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.profile-image-container .mask-layer span,
.profile-image-container .mask-layer i {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-image-container">
  <img class="profile-image" src=http://nineplanets.org/images/earth.jpg alt="Profile img 0313">
  <div class="mask-layer">
    <div class="update-pic">
      <span>Update Photo</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcfj0y3a/2/).

On my site it looks better, the mask actually sits centered over the image.  But it still flashes.

Also this is important, I want the cursor to always appear as a link.  Currently when the user hovers over the text, the cursor changes to the text bar and I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using just css:

```
.mask-layer{
  visibility: hidden:
}
.profile-image:hover mask-layer{
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I've updated your jsfiddle with the above css and it does not flash.

http://jsfiddle.net/fcfj0y3a/3/

for your click part, use:

```
$('.mask-layer').on('click', function(e) {
  alert(e.target, 'was clicked');
});
```

Comment: cool that solves the flashing, but what about the cursor change when I hover over the text.  I need to hook a jquery event to clicking on the mask and I need it to work if the user clicks over the text in the span as well

Comment: check out my latest edit. I didn't put the `cursor: pointer;` in the jsfiddle but  that is how you force the cursor change. on the click thing, for jQuery use: `$('.mask-layer').on('click', function(e) {alert(e.target, 'was clicked!');}` (I'm writing this in a comment so the layout isn't completely correct but the code is what you need.

Comment: okay I've put the jQuery code into my answer so it is easier to read (and also a syntax error was fixed)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use javascript if you just want to show the mask when user's

mouse hovers on the image

here is the demo. basically, I just add another css rule

```
.profile-image-container:hover .mask-layer {
  display: flex;
}
```

and make the `mask-layer` default to `display: none`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2sjx2has/1/)